# Windows Phone 7 transparent WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to a have a transparent WebBrowser component to be displayed on top of other components. I have been trying with a transparent Background WebBrowser property, different transparent colors for html page, but it doesn't seem to work.

It is any way in which I can do this?

Comment: The same thing was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125867/making-webbrowser-transparent

Comment: I seen it as well, though it only offers a workaround. I would appreciate any tips on WebBrowser transparency or to get more opinions before considering it not possible. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply transparency to a WebBrowser control because it's not a "true" Silverlight control. It's a native control in a Silverlight wrapper so that it can be used LIKE a regular Silverlight control.
As a wrapped native control it handles its drawing itself and doesn't go through the Silverlight drawing pipeline and so can't have transparency applied at that time. As it doesn't make sense for the web browser to include transparency when used as a standalone app it doesn't have this facility built in and so can't be used when used in an embedded manner.

For workarounds, see the answers at [Making WebBrowser Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125867/making-webbrowser-transparent)

Comment: to wrap it up, for me the trick with Opacity did the job, thx Matt Lacey

Comment: Have you managed to make it transparent? We're facing just the same. Can we discuss?

Comment: I have just seen your post, yes it did work by using the Opacity field.