# WP 7.5 - Is there a control capable of formatting HTML available?

Tags: html, controls, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'd like to display some formatted Html as a part of the app I'm working on.  Do any controls exist that properly display Html on Windows Phone Mango?  One requirement is that the background needs the ability to be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebBrowser` control in Microsoft.Phone with the `NavigateToString` method to render some Html I believe, but I don't think you can have it be transparent unfortunately ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125867/making-webbrowser-transparent))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RichTextBox` if you're targeting mango. You'll need to do a little work with it, but a tiny bit of html parsing could be all you need.[Windows Phone 7 Mango: First look at RichTextBox control](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control)

What color is your background? If it's black or white, you can wrap your html fragment in HTML which can change the layout/background/etc based on the user's color scheme, etc..

[Integrated Links and Styling for Windows Phone 7 WebBrowser Control](http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/07/integrated-links-and-styling-for-windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control/)

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing some C# work for WPF a while back I ended up ditching the WebBrowser control for Awesomium(http://awesomium.com/) due to its limitations. The features page says it supports "Windowless Rendering" to "Render web-pages to any graphics surface, 3D texture, or otherwise. Perfect for use in games, multi-touch simulations, and more." You should be able to create a transparent control using this.

There is a C# version called awesomiumsharp, in case you can't find it.

If this solution is too much then I think Willmel's answer will suffice. You should be able to change the background of the control at runtime, though I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do it.