# XAML: WebBrower Background Color?

Tags: xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="number" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Margin="24,0,0,0" InputScope="Number" MaxLength="3" />
        <Button Content="find" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="269,0,0,0" Width="161" RenderTransformOrigin="0.743,0.541" Name="searchbutton" Click="search"/>

    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,84,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Background="Black" Foreground="Black"/>
    </Grid>
```

Here is my xaml code for initializing web browser in my app. But, the web browser appears in white color. I have given all coloring properties as much i know. But it stills in same white color. I need to make it transparent.

Here's my sample image files I captured  - http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/6956/rt0n.png

Best answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: See my answer with code to make WebBrowser background - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19034336/1219241

Comment: See my answer with code to make WebBrowser background - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19034336/1219241

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color for webbrowser. Just look at this answer

[How to make Webbrowser control with black background in Windows Phone 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124166/how-to-make-webbrowser-control-with-black-background-in-windows-phone-7-1)

Comment: that's too complicated. I cant understand anything from it.