# Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser Background Transparent

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, transparency, background-color

i'm developing a WP8 app, and i'm using a webbrowser to show html content.

Im trying to make the background of the browser trasparent. Is it possible?

I've already tried many things, like change webbrowser opacity or edit body content from html but any of them have worked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm pretty positive [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125867/making-webbrowser-transparent) still applies to wp8 also.

Comment: how can i inject via script an image background into html content?
thanks a lot, i think this is the only solution.